# Unexplained crashes generating video

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios5, core-graphics

I develop some application for iPad which includes media capturing and exporting. The code contains this part:

```
BOOL appended;
    if(input.readyForMoreMediaData==YES){
        //CVPixelBufferRef videobuf=[self pixelBufferFromCGImage];
        //grab the view and convert it into image
        CGSize imgsize=self.imageSource.frame.size;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgsize);
        [self.imageSource.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage* grabbedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        CVReturn cvErr = kCVReturnSuccess;
        CGImageRef image = (CGImageRef) [grabbedImage CGImage];

        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                                 nil];
        CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

        CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, imgsize.width,
                                              imgsize.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options, 
                                              &pxbuffer);

        NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
        void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
        NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

        CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, imgsize.width,
                                                     imgsize.height, 8, 4*imgsize.width, rgbColorSpace, 
                                                     kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
        NSParameterAssert(context);
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), 
                                               CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
        CGContextRelease(context);

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

        appended = [pxlBufAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pxbuffer withPresentationTime:presentationTime];
        CVBufferRelease(pxbuffer );
    }
```

Almost any correction in this code crashes the application with the message:

SetErrAndBail() in line #10597 in /SourceCache/CoreMediaH264SWLib_Sim/CoreMediaH264SWLib-407/Standalone/../JVTLib_Turbo/JVTLib.cpp

However, after Clean+Rebuild the same code is executed without crash.

How can I eliminate that crash?

Comment: You might have better luck if you indicate what the stack trace of that error is, and where the code you pasted is from.

Comment: There is no stack trace available, it looks like some assertion popped up in some codec...

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

You are getting crashes because the system is running out of memory. Create a pixel buffer pool and reuse pixel buffers instead of trying to just create one every time and the crashes will likely go away. You should also use BGRA format pixels instead of ARGB format pixels to avoid having the system doing a byte swap behind the scenes.